# Python - Convert a matrix to edge list/long form

Tags: python, matrix, adjacency-matrix, matrix-transform

I have a very large csv file, with a matrix like this:

```
null,A,B,C

A,0,2,3

B,3,4,2

C,1,2,4
```

It is always a n*n matrix. The first column and the first row are the names. I want to convert it to a 3 column format (also could be called edge list, long form, etc) like this:

```
A,A,0

A,B,2

A,C,3

B,A,3

B,B,4

B,C,2

C,A,1

C,B,2

C,C,4
```

I have used:

```
row = 0
for line in fin:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    col = 0
    tokens = line.split(",")
    for t in tokens:
        fout.write("\n%s,%s,%s"%(row,col,t))
        col += 1
    row += 1
```

doesn't work...

Could you please help? Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to enumerate the column titles as your print out the individual cells.

For a matrix file **mat.csv**:

```
null,A,B,C
A,0,2,3
B,3,4,2
C,1,2,4
```

The following program:

```
csv = open("mat.csv")

columns = csv.readline().strip().split(',')[1:]
for line in csv:
    tokens = line.strip().split(',')
    row = tokens[0]
    for column, cell in zip(columns,tokens[1:]):
        print '{},{},{}'.format(row,column,cell)
```

prints out:

```
A,A,0
A,B,2
A,C,3
B,A,3
B,B,4
B,C,2
C,A,1
C,B,2
C,C,4
```

For generating the **upper diagonal**, you can use the following script:

```
csv = open("mat.csv")

columns = csv.readline().strip().split(',')[1:]
for i, line in enumerate(csv):
    tokens = line.strip().split(',')
    row = tokens[0]
    for column, cell in zip(columns[i:],tokens[i+1:]):
        print '{},{},{}'.format(row,column,cell)
```

which results in the output:

```
A,A,0
A,B,2
A,C,3
B,B,4
B,C,2
C,C,4
```

Comment: Instead of col=0, set col=row

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip the first column in each line:

```
for t in tokens[1:]:
```